# On boundedness of $\int_{\mathbb{T}}\mid\log(|f(rz)|) \mid d\lambda $ if $f$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, hardy-spaces

I have some problems proving that if $f$ is analytic in the open disc, then

$$\int_{\mathbb{T}}\mid\log(|f(rz)|)\mid \,< \infty.$$

I seen some proofs when $f$ is non zero since then we have no problem with the logarithm and we get that the integrand is the real part of an analytic function. But I can't seem to find a way around this even with subharmonic functions.

Suggestions?

It is possible that this statement is false and that the person who wrote it forgot to assume that $f$ is in $H^p$.

Comment: if $f$ is analytic on $|z| < 1$ then for $r < 1$ : $\int_0^{2\pi} |\log f(r e^{it})| dt$ converges, it is because $f$ has zeros of finite order, and  $\log x$ is locally integrable

Comment: @user1952009 what tools/definitions is need for such an argument?

Comment: it is the basic theory of holomorphic/analytic functions : they have a finite number of zeros and of finite order on any compact

Comment: (the only exception being $f = 0$)

Comment: @user1952009 Ah you mean idenitcally zero!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct proof : Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $|z| < 1$ and not identically zero.

- for any $|a| < 1$ and $|z|$ small enough,
  $f(a+z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ so if $f(a) = 0$ then $f(a+z) \sim c_k z^k$,  so $a$ is a zero of order $k$.
- take a compact in $|z| < 1$, and suppose $f(z)$ has infinitely many zeros $a_1,a_2, \ldots$. Then  $(a_n)$ has at least one convergent subsequence $a_{n_1},a_{n_2}, \ldots$. Let $A = \lim_k a_{n_k}$. By continuity $f(A) = \lim_k f(a_{n_k}) = \lim_k 0 = 0$. So $A$ is a non isolated zero of $f$, a contradiction with $f(A+z) \sim c_k z^k$ for some $k, c_k \ne 0$.
- hence on $|z| = r < 1$, $f$ is $C^\infty$ and has finitely many zeros of finite order, so that $\int_0^{2\pi} |\log f(r e^{it})| dt$ converges.

Comment: I dont get is the last part, this only give me for some $r$. According to me there are some $r$ for which the log becomes to big.It will be zero set tho,I think but Im not sure..

Comment: @User231241 it is your question. if you ask about $\sup_{r < 1}$ of course  it is not always bounded, take $g(z)$ not in $H^1$ and $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$

Comment: Ah, given $r$ we converge since its bounded on complement of zero set, right?

Comment: @User231241 for a given $r < 1$ it converges because of what I wrote

Comment: Im sorry I dont see it, Why cant $f$ stay to close to zero for to long on the $r$-circle because of this.

Comment: try with $f(z) = e^{h(z)} (z-r)^3(z+r)^{26}$ where $h(z)$ is analytic on $|z| < 1$. no matter how large is $h(z)$ it is bounded on the circle $|z| = r$, i.e. only the zeros of $f$ matter, and their $\log$ is locally integrable

Comment: @User231241 now what I wrote in my answer is enough : remember that a continuous function cannot be as close as it wants to $0$ without having in fine a zero, so excluding a neighborhood of its zeros, $|f(z)|$ has a minimum (and a maximum) on $|z| = r$, and together with the fact that $\log f(z)$ is locally integrable around the zeros of $f$ (since around a zero : $f(z+a) \sim C z^k$)...

Comment: Can you please clarify " remember that a continuous function cannot be as close as it wants to 0 without having in fine a zero, so excluding a neighborhood of its zeros, |f(z)| has a minimum (and a maximum) on |z|=f" Do you mean a zero of infinite multiplicity?

Comment: @User231241 come on... if you remove $|z-a| < \epsilon$ for each of its zeros, then $|f(z)|$ is bounded below and above on $|z| \le r$  (simply because it is continuous)

Comment: @User231241 now stop asking some details, and learn to make your own proofs (as I did)